# Using induction prove $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{k}{k-1}=\binom{n+1}{n-1}$

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{k}{k-1}=\binom{n+1}{n-1}$

We are supposed to use induction to prove this inequality. After the base case, I tried to use the definition $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. But the results were convoluted and did not lead to a satisfactory proof.

A guide through the inductive steps would be helpful.

Comment: You are just summing the first $n$ integers.  $\binom{k}{k-1}=k$....

Comment: And you wrote "inequality".  Do you mean "equality"?

Comment: For the induction step you will need to show that $\binom{n+1}{n-1}+\binom{n+1}{n}=\binom{n+2}{n}$. This can be proved by manipulation. It is also a consequence of the Pascal Identity.  Weird question!

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$\binom{n+1}{n-1} = \frac{(n + 1)!}{(n + 1)! \ 2!} = \frac{1}{2}n(n + 1)
$$

(Which is the sum of the first $n$ numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=m$.  Then assume
$$\sum_{k=1}^m\binom{k}{k-1}=\binom{m+1}{m-1}$$
Now for $n=m+1$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\binom{k}{k-1}=\binom{m+1}{m-1}+\binom{m+1}{m}=\binom{m+2}{m}$$
It shouldn't be hard to show the last step above.  But this is the induction step that you were looking for.